# Network interface disappeared

Tags: networking

I have several instances of a VirtualBox VM created by Vagrant. This VM has the network interface `eth1` defined as:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:61:1D:AA  
          inet addr:192.168.33.10  Bcast:192.168.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe61:1daa/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5095882 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8754306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1412438221 (1.3 GiB)  TX bytes:10704698155 (9.9 GiB)
```

Yesterday one of the VM instances lost the `eth1` interface. When I do `ifconfig -a` I get:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:1B:06:06  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe1b:606/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:817 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:80141 (78.2 KiB)  TX bytes:111329 (108.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24798 (24.2 KiB)  TX bytes:24798 (24.2 KiB)
```

But I can see the definition of `eth1` in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`.

```
# PCI device 0x8086:0x100e (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:f0:34:82", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

Also `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` has:

```
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.33.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEVICE=eth1
PEERDNS=no
#VAGRANT-END
```

So it looks like all the definitions are there but `eth1` is not being created. Rebooting and restarting the network service doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try `ifup eth1 && tail -f /var/log/messages` and watch the output. 
Has the vm more than one virtual interface? 
If yes, you could delete all the network interface scripts such as ifcfg-eth0, ifcfg-eth1... and recreate them. Maybe theres a problem within your other config files for the interfaces which leads to this problem. The `messages` log normally tells you where the exactly problem occurs.

Comment: The output is `Device eth1 does not seem to be present, delaying initialization`. That's the only relevant thing I see. The VM has another interface `eth0`. How do I recreate the scripts after deleting them? Simply create new files with the same content?

Comment: After deleting the scripts you simply need to create new ones. You could fix that problem too by looking into your network setting in your vm host. Copy the layer2 adress of the virtual nic for your vm into the ifcfg config file (e.g. ifcfg-eth0) as HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX